# Auto parameter type in lambda causes "Use 'template' keyword to treat..." error

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, auto

I have this code

```cpp
struct TestClass
{
    template <typename T>
    T get()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

void invoke(const std::function<void(const TestClass& c)>& func)
{
    func(TestClass());
}
```

Now if I use `invoke` as following there is no problems

```cpp
invoke([](TestClass tc) {
    tc.get<int>();
});
```

But if I change the parameter type in the lambda function to `auto` I get the following error. I know that I can fix it by inserting the `template` keyword before `get`, but what I'm not understanding is why I get this error?

```
error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'get' as a dependent template name
    tc.get<int>();
       ^
       template

// Happens when using `auto` as parameter type
invoke([](auto tc) {
    tc.get<int>();
});
```

I'm using clang v10.0

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/580083)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have a template type (in the form of `auto`) instead of a concrete type `TestClass`, the `get` function is dependent, and therefore you need to qualify it with the `template` keyword:

```
tc.template get<int>();
```

Comment: I don't understand why that `auto` doesn't give a concrete type. Isn't `TestClass` the only possible type for the parameter?

Comment: @PeterBechP A lambda is callable because it compiles to a small class with `operator()` defined. When the parameter is specified as `auto` ( a generic lambda), the parameter to the resulting `operator()` becomes a template parameter. (so `operator()` is templated). Since `get` is a templated name, the compiler requires you to disambiguate the expression by inserting the `template` keyword.

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you! :-)